# Calculating index scores for overlap between categorical variables

Tags: probability, distributions, categorical-data

Lets say I have the following dataset, it has two categorical variables `domain` & `country`, and a `count` column. So each row shows me how many times someone from a specific country visited a specific domain.

Now the size of each country and domain can vary greatly! So what I would to do is to calculate some scores to help get some relative measures which would throw out the fact that some larger domains are more popular in all countries for example.

What are some approaches, please could you provide their names, a brief explanation as to why each one could be suitable and the tradeoffs.

So far I have had most success with [Pointwise Mutual Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information)

Ideally the final scores will be well distributed and in some nice range (0 to 1).